# i have a date column so now i just need month and year to be displayed in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008

`SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(4), getdate(), 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), getdate(), 120) as Month 
from tablename`

The output for this is

```
Month
Jun 2014
```

But i want the output to show as

```
Month
04,2012
```

Comment: you want to subtract 2 from month and year and show it in this format ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to show Jun 2014 as 04-2012 (April 2012)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to -2 from both...

```
SELECT RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),2)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

You don't' need to query a table to use `GETDATE()`/`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `fnFormatDate` function defined [here](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/).

Or you could just do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(2), getdate(), 101) +',' + convert(char(4), getdate(), 120)
```